# how can i make a queue in ml

Tags: queue, ml

i am writting a program in ml and i am trying to make a queue that consists of a tuple of integers.But it doesnt work!here is my code.

```
let     
val fif1 = Queue.mkQueue (() ,()  )
in #2 (bfs1 (array1, 0, n, Queue.enqueue (fif1 , (c,0) ) ))
end
```

where c is an integer.
the compiler error is this:

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [type mismatch]
operator domain: {2:'Y; 'Z}
operand:         square array * 'X * int * (int * int) Queue.queue
               -> square array * int * int * (int * int) Queue.queue
in expression:
(fn {2=2,...} => 2) bfs1
```

any help would be very very useful!thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the [Queue structure in SML/NJ](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/queue.html).

Very briefly, that's an implementation of *mutable* queues. The signature provides the constructor `mkQueue` which has the type `unit -> 'a queue`. You're calling `mkQueue` with a value of type `unit * unit`:

```
Queue.mkQueue ((), ())
```

No matter what type of queue you want, you should call `mkQueue` with just `()`. Here's an example, this makes a new queue and adds a couple of pairs of ints to it:

Construct the queue (I had to add a type annotation at the REPL due to the value restriction, you may not have to do this in a source file that you compile, I'm not sure)

```
val q = Queue.mkQueue () : (int * int) Queue.queue
```

Then add two things to it:

```
val _ = ( Queue.enqueue (q, (1, 2))
        ; Queue.enqueue (q, (3, 4)))
```

Get them out, pattern match with constants to confirm that it's working:

```
val (1, 2) = Queue.dequeue q
val (3, 4) = Queue.dequeue q
```

Your error message is a bit perplexing to me, it looks like you're trying to apply `#2` (which selects the second element from a tuple) from the function `bfs1`, which of course is not a tuple. But your code is properly parenthesized, so I wonder if you loaded some older code that caused that message?

Try to load the folloing code in a fresh REPL, along with the rest of your code (i.e. stop the SML/NJ process altogether and start a new one with your code). It's hard for me otest this has there's some code missing (the variables `c`, `n`, `array1`, `bfs1`)

```
let
   val fif1 = Queue.mkQueue ()
in
   #2 (bfs1 (array1, 0, n, Queue.enqueue (fif1, (c, 0))))
end
```